# Rselenium executable does not exist

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I try to run RSelenium using the following:

```
library("RSelenium")
#start RSelenium server
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$open()
```

However, in `rsDriver()`, I receive this error:

```
Selenium message:The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\kira\Documents

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I have download the standalone jar of Selenium and put it into the path but the error does not disappear. Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html), it looks like you should be starting the server from the command terminal.  Of course, you can do this from R with the [`system2`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) command, but probably easier to start the `jar` from a terminal first for debugging.

> Alternatively you can run the binary manually. Open a console in your
>   OS and navigate to where the binary is located and run:
>
> `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar`
>
> By default the
>   Selenium Server listens for connections on port 4444.
>
> Note for Mac OSX: The default port 4444 is sometimes used by other
>   programs such as kerberos. In our examples we use port 4445 in respect
>   of this and for cdonsistency with the Docker vignette.

Afterwards, connecting from R:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444L
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )

remDr$open()

remDr$getStatus()
```

Comment: Thank you I run the executable jar from cmd I will try port 4444 but until now I was running Rselenium without need to run first the executable

Comment: You're right, `rsDriver` is a wrapper I was unfamiliar with.  Can you turn on `verbose=TRUE` and include the output, so we get a bit more detail about what is going on?